What is the proper way of calculating peak acceleration of a object dropped on a spring?
I have dropped a small object on spring. This object has guardrails so it moves just translationaly in axis of gravitational force. I have also recorded the fall with speedcamera. Now I want to calculate the peak acceleration.
For this I have tried various different aproaches that are listed here on desmos. I have derived these equations with help of endevco and this paper.


The issue I am seeing is that different aproaches give quite different results. I have busted approach 5 which is based on displacement datapoints from speedcamera. There is a huge role in how I manually take the points, not even talking about making twice the discrete differentiation to get the acceleration. I have also tried to use curve fitting in excel but without much success. I have tried to calculate it multiple times but the final value was fluctuating something like +-30% which is to much.


The result is almost the same for approach 1, 2 and 6. But when it comes to 3 and 4, which are based on spring compression and energies the values of acceleration I get are like +30% higher than for 1,2 and 6. So my hypothesis was that the energy approach is ideal case, meaning it is expecting the body to rebound to the initial drop height. Yet there is obviously some energy loss in the system... Tiny bit in is consumed by air resistance and the remainder is probably consumed by spring hysteresis. I can also confirm that from speedcamera, the rebound height is about half of the drop height. So my thought was okay, acceleration from this aproach is bigger but it doesnt count with energy loss which is causing that the peak acceleration is smaller.
But I got little bit confused from the approach 4. This aproach uses spring compression observed in speed camera, like the real one. And the equation seems kinda unbreakable.
Am I missing something? Have I made some wring assumption?
I will appreciate any insight, thanks John:)
EDIT:


It would help if you provided some date points.  Have you tried using Tracker?

Energy approach is probably in error as the collision between falling object and the spring is inelastic.

Unfortunately I cannot do that since the data are protected and sharing would be information leakage. I have used PFV4 software for manual tracking:
https://photron.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/PFV4-2020.03.03_Online-Res.pdf

I think that you best bet is to measure position as a function of time as you are then using kinematic ideas.  Then do some manual analysis of the data. Feynman has a section on 9-8 Numerical solution of the equations.

Calculating coefficient of restitution it gives me value of 0.7 and 0.67 for the case of fall from double the height. Simple multiplication with the results yields to small values... It seems I need to multiply it rather with 0.8 and 0.75.

I have done the position as a function in time measurement already using photron. Then tried to do differentiation in excel to get velocity and then acceleration. Yet it was quite innacurate. I have also tried to fit 6th order polynomial to the distance in time graph and perform the differentiation on it. It gave better results but still off and the value wasnt replicable much. What do you mean exactly by manual analysis?
I have also tried 5th rational polynomial fit as mentioned in "the paper" but excel wasnt able to find good solution. Just to mention the contact time is around 4ms.

Initially forget about the curve fitting and construct a graph of average velocity in a given time interval against time.  Are the date points such that you can sensibly measure a gradient?

What do you mea nexactly by average velocity? I have made differentiation from displacement over time spanning over 3 points.. Like (d3-d1)/(t3-t1). So I think this is already some kind of averaging. Unfortunately it isnt smooth. I have added first portion of velocity to the post, it ends just before it hits zero and rebounds..

So the initial gradient will be less than $g$ and then you have some very good data points to estimate the rate of negative acceleration. I do not understand why you have a concern?

Shouldnt be the initial gradient precisely equal to g (minus the air resistance)? I think the problem might be that as you can se, the gradient during impact is very steep, which means that it is badly-conditioned and the result is just way off:/
How would you get the acceleration from those datapoints?


The result is almost the same for approach 1, 2 and 6.

That seems like you have a good answer then. The other two techniques are based on an unrealistic simplifying assumption.
